# execute php script from command line on ubuntu

Tags: php, ssh, command-line-interface

I can run facebook.php script from ssh below:

```
cd /var/www/
php facebook.php
```

But I want to run to script 1 line command because i want to use it on cron. Like this:

```
php /var/www/facebook.php
```

I tried other commands on ssh but dont worked. Only first command is worked for me

Comment: You should try it with the complete path to `php`.

Comment: I am trying but dont works for me: `/usr/bin/php /var/www/facebook.php`

Comment: What does the complete cron line look like?

Comment: How Can I Look That?

Comment: @Ayxan Can you run `whereis php` from your terminal to confirm the complete path to your `php`?

Comment: @isim `php: /usr/bin/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz`

Answer (score 0):

if /usr/bin/php /var/www/facebook.php is not working, it might a case of your php path is different then /usr/bin/php.